# NSXMLParser Three Same Elements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, nsxmlparser

I am using NSXMLParser to parse this XML: http://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/topsongs/limit=50/explicit=true/xml. I am trying to parse an element called "im:image". My problem is that there are three elements with the name "im:image". How can I only parse the data from the second "im:image", or how can I add each single one to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `didStartElement` method of your custom delegate, check `attributes` and ensure that it has `height` set to `60` (each of the 'same' XML elements has a different height attribute). The `attributes` is an `NSDictionary` with keys for name of the attributes and values for values of the attributes. Here is an example of roughly how you would do it:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
  if ([[attributeDict objectForKey:@"height"] isEqualToString:@"60"]) {
    NSLog(@"store");
  }
}
```

Comment: Store it however you want. Add it to an array, a set, a dictionary. It depends what you are using it for and how you want to retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks, How could I get the image url from this as it is not in the found characters method?

Comment: That's strange, it should be found in the `foundCharacters`. Try putting an NSLog for the data that is found in this function and make sure you aren't just missing it. The inner contents of an XML element will always be 'found' in that method.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the best way to do it, but when something like this happened to me I simply created a `NSInteger` named `counter`.  Then in `didStartElement` I did this:  (I was looking for the second element in my case)

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"yweather:forecast"])
    {
        int code = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"code"] intValue];
        if (counter == 0) {
        }
        if (counter == 1) {
            conditionCode = code;
        }
        counter ++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the issues with this approach is that if the XML document being generate has the order of elements changed (for whatever reason) this will produce different results. It usually isn't a problem if you generate the document yourself, but will pose a risk when accessing an external service (such as the itunes data).